# Time Limit for a command to run in cmd

Tags: windows, curl, cmd

I'm writing a batch file which is having several commands and giving output as given by each command. But, some commands are not working which is taking the code longer to execute. I want every command to be run for 10 seconds and if output does not come, then abort this command and run next command in batch file.

```
curl URL1
curl URL2
curl URL3
curl URL4
```

If URL2 is not working, it is taking a longer time to execute. I want every `curl` command to be checked for 10 seconds and abort and run next `curl` command.

Comment: What have you done to try this yourself? This would be pretty simple in PowerShell.

Comment: Why not use the `--max-time` parameter for curl? I'm assuming by curl you mean *actual* curl and not some aliased command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you're writing a batch file I'm going to assume that you're using the Windows port of the cURL commandline utility, not the alias `curl` for the PowerShell cmdlet `Invoke-WebRequest`.

The cURL utility has [2 parameters](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) that control timeouts:

> `--connect-timeout <seconds>`
>   Maximum time in seconds that you allow the connection to the server to take. This only limits the connection phase, once curl has connected this option is of no more use. See also the `-m`/`--max-time` option.
>
> [...]
>
> `-m/--max-time <seconds>`
>   Maximum time in seconds that you allow the whole operation to take. This is useful for preventing your batch jobs from hanging for hours due to slow networks or links going down. See also the `--connect-timeout` option.

So you should be able to run your statements like this:

```
curl --connect-timeout 10 --max-time 10 URL
```